# wifijammer.py issue MacOSx

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I'm trying to test out https://github.com/DanMcInerney/wifijammer but i get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wifijammer.py", line 371, in <module>
    mon_iface = get_mon_iface(args)
  File "wifijammer.py", line 52, in get_mon_iface
    monitors, interfaces = iwconfig()
  File "wifijammer.py", line 69, in iwconfig
    proc = Popen(['iwconfig'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=DN)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1308, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I realize that it maybe because MacOSX does not have iwconfig.....but if that is indeed the issue is there any work around? Any source modification I can make so that this error doesn't occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

wifijammer.py seems to have only designed to work on Linux.

It may be able to modified to run on OSX, but there's some specific things that have to change. It seems to be requiring the command line `iwconfig` tool to be installed, which it uses to determine the interface name of your wireless card.

[Report the issue to their issue tracker](https://github.com/DanMcInerney/wifijammer/issues), or modify the script yourself to use `airport -I`, or `ifconfig` instead. Lastly, you could just hackishly change the function to use `en1` (which is generally the wifi card on most macs). YMMV.

Comment: @user3140562: Maybe, but that's a completely separate issue that you should ask the script author. In general, it might (though I doubt it), if the network card is allowed to go into promiscuous mode and the virtual machine is given direct access to the network card instead of a virtual NIC. Please accept this answer if it answered the original question.